# Adding values together

Tags: javascript

I finally got my previous question regarding "if else statements" but I cannot get the last line of code in the Javascript to add the numbers together, I keep getting NaN as the result, which I now know is Not a Number.

If anyone could point me in the right direction to add the 9 values up it would be appreciated.

HTML

```html
<p id="payout-text">     
  <b> To calculate Prize distribution each Player will receive:</b>
  &ensp; Enter the Prize Pool.             
  <br>
  <span id="prizepool-input"> &emsp; <input type="text" id="prizepool" /> </span>
  <br>
  &emsp;  Enter number of Players.
  <br>
  <span id="players-input"> &emsp; <input type="text" id="players" oninput="multiplyBy()" Value=""/> </span> 
  <br>
  <br>  &emsp;  1st Place: <span id = "payout-first"></span>
  <br>  &emsp; 2nd Place: <span id = "payout-second"></span> 
  <br>  &emsp; 3rd Place: <span id = "payout-third"></span>
  <br>  &emsp; 4th Place: <span id = "payout-fourth"></span>
  <br>  &emsp; 5th Place: <span id = "payout-fifth"></span>
  <br>  &emsp; 6th Place: <span id = "payout-sixth"></span>
  <br>  &emsp; 7th Place: <span id = "payout-seventh"></span>
  <br>  &emsp; 8th Place: <span id = "payout-eighth"></span>
  <br>  &emsp; 9th Place: <span id = "payout-ninth"></span>
  <br>
  <br>&emsp; &emsp;  &emsp; Total: <span id = "payout-all"></span> 
</p>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
function multiplyBy() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("prizepool").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("players").value;

  prize1 = document.getElementById("payout-first").value;
  prize2 = document.getElementById("payout-second").value;
  prize3 = document.getElementById("payout-third").value;
  prize4 = document.getElementById("payout-fourth").value;
  prize5 = document.getElementById("payout-fifth").value;
  prize6 = document.getElementById("payout-sixth").value;
  prize7 = document.getElementById("payout-seventh").value;
  prize8 = document.getElementById("payout-eighth").value;
  prize9 = document.getElementById("payout-ninth").value;
  
  if (num2 <= 4) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 100)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 14) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 65)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 24) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 50)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 34) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 45)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 44) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 40)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 54) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 36)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 64) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 35)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 34)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 32)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
                        
  if (num2 <= 4) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil (num1 * 0) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 14) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 35)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 24) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 30)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 34) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 28)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 44) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 24)/100) .toLocaleString(); 
  }
  else if (num2 <= 54) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 23)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 22)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 21)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 20)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  
  if (num2 <= 14) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil (0) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 24) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 20)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 34) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 17)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 44) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 16)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 54) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 15)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 64) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 14)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 13)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 11)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 24) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil (0) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 34) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 10)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 44) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 12)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 54) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 11)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 64) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 10)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 9)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 9)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 34) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil (0) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 44) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 8)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 54) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 8)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 64) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 8)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 7)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 7)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 44) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil (0) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 54) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 7)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 64) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 6)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 6)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 6)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 54) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-seventh").innerHTML = Math.ceil (0) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 64) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-seventh").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 5)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-seventh").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 5)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-seventh").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 6)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 64) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-eighth").innerHTML = Math.ceil (0) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-eighth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 5)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-eighth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 5)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 74) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-ninth").innerHTML = Math.ceil (0) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else if (num2 <= 84) { 
    document.getElementById("payout-ninth").innerHTML = Math.ceil ((num1 * 4)/100) .toLocaleString();
  }
  else { 
    document.getElementById("payout-ninth").innerHTML = Math.ceil (0) .toLocaleString();
  }

  {document.getElementById("payout-all").innerHTML = Math.ceil (prize1 + prize2  + prize3 + prize4 + prize5 + prize6 + prize7 + prize8 + prize9) .toLocaleString();}

}
</script>
```

Comment: well first, `span`s don't have values, and even if they did, you still have to cast it to a number

Answer (score 1):

To get the content inside a `span`, you need to use either `textContent` or `innerText`.

```js
function multiplyBy() {
  num1 = document.getElementById("prizepool").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("players").value;

  prize1 = +document.getElementById("payout-first").textContent;
  prize2 = +document.getElementById("payout-second").textContent;
  prize3 = +document.getElementById("payout-third").textContent;
  prize4 = +document.getElementById("payout-fourth").textContent;
  prize5 = +document.getElementById("payout-fifth").textContent;
  prize6 = +document.getElementById("payout-sixth").textContent;
  prize7 = +document.getElementById("payout-seventh").textContent;
  prize8 = +document.getElementById("payout-eighth").textContent;
  prize9 = +document.getElementById("payout-ninth").textContent;


  if (num2 <= 4) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 100) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 14) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 65) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 24) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 50) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 34) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 45) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 44) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 40) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 54) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 36) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 35) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 34) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-first").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 32) / 100).toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 4) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil(num1 * 0).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 14) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 35) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 24) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 30) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 34) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 28) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 44) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 24) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 54) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 23) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 22) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 21) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-second").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 20) / 100).toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 14) {
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil(0).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 24) {
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 20) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 34) {
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 17) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 44) {
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 16) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 54) {
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 15) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 14) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 13) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-third").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 11) / 100).toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 24) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil(0).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 34) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 10) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 44) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 12) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 54) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 11) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 10) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 9) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fourth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 9) / 100).toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 34) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil(0).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 44) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 8) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 54) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 8) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 8) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 7) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-fifth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 7) / 100).toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 44) {
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil(0).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 54) {
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 7) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 6) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 6) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-sixth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 6) / 100).toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 54) {
    document.getElementById("payout-seventh").innerHTML = Math.ceil(0).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-seventh").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 5) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-seventh").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 5) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-seventh").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 6) / 100).toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 64) {
    document.getElementById("payout-eighth").innerHTML = Math.ceil(0).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-eighth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 5) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-eighth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 5) / 100).toLocaleString();
  }

  if (num2 <= 74) {
    document.getElementById("payout-ninth").innerHTML = Math.ceil(0).toLocaleString();
  } else if (num2 <= 84) {
    document.getElementById("payout-ninth").innerHTML = Math.ceil((num1 * 4) / 100).toLocaleString();
  } else {
    document.getElementById("payout-ninth").innerHTML = Math.ceil(0).toLocaleString();
  }

  document.getElementById("payout-all").innerHTML = Math.ceil(prize1 + prize2 + prize3 + prize4 + prize5 + prize6 + prize7 + prize8 + prize9).toLocaleString();
}
```

```html
<p id="payout-text">
  <b> To calculate Prize distribution each Player will receive:</b> &ensp; Enter the Prize Pool.
  <br>
  <span id="prizepool-input"> &emsp; <input type="text" id="prizepool" /> </span>
  <br> &emsp; Enter number of Players.
  <br>
  <span id="players-input"> &emsp; <input type="text" id="players" oninput="multiplyBy()" Value=""/> </span>
  <br>
  <br> &emsp; 1st Place: <span id="payout-first"></span>
  <br> &emsp; 2nd Place: <span id="payout-second"></span>
  <br> &emsp; 3rd Place: <span id="payout-third"></span>
  <br> &emsp; 4th Place: <span id="payout-fourth"></span>
  <br> &emsp; 5th Place: <span id="payout-fifth"></span>
  <br> &emsp; 6th Place: <span id="payout-sixth"></span>
  <br> &emsp; 7th Place: <span id="payout-seventh"></span>
  <br> &emsp; 8th Place: <span id="payout-eighth"></span>
  <br> &emsp; 9th Place: <span id="payout-ninth"></span>
  <br>
  <br>&emsp; &emsp; &emsp; Total: <span id="payout-all"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks Deepak, I tried changing the last line of code in the javascript from innerHTML to textContent and then innerText, but neither gave me the total.

Comment: You should not change innerHTML. You have to change `value` to `textContent`. Please refer to the code in my answer where I have used `textContent`.

Comment: Thanks again Deepak, I changed value to textContent and it did not work, I then changed value to InnerText and this also did not work. When I ran your snippet - entering 21900 in the Prizepool input and then 83 in the Players input, all 9 Prizes display correctly, but the Total still shows NaN.